# Python 3 character encoding on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, unicode

Can't even understand where the issue resides..

I have a python 3.6 virtual environment, have a python source file which I run within that environment - it basically lists files from a folder and tries to read them. The file names can have special characters.

Each time I run the source file, when it lists the files with glob it uses ascii to decode the filenames (hence the '?'characters) and sys.getfilesystemencoding() returns ascii, 
although

when I run the same glob command within a terminal, it uses the utf-8 encoding and outputs the file names correctly

Why so?

The locale command returns

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

The code:

```
import os, sys
import glob

folderpath = '<path_to_folder>'

def test():
    files = [item for sublist in [glob.glob(os.path.join(folderpath, e)) for e in ['*.zip', '*.tar.gz']] for item in sublist]
    try:
        # select the 1st path
        filepath = files[0]
        print('filepath = ' + filepath)
        print('fs_encoding = ' + sys.getfilesystemencoding())
        print(sys.stdout.isatty())
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        test()
```

Comment: what does `print(sys.stdout.isatty())` display (when added as a line in the same script you're talking about)

Comment: @jedwards, it says False

Comment: Try starting your script with the following: `LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8 python <your script>`, or `LANG=C.UTF-8 python <your script>`, or `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python <your script>`

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: ok, I completely isolated that code and put it into a separate script which I added to supervisor - the output is correct, now when that code is ran as part of an apache/daphne command - the output is wrong